# Handle socket descriptors like file descriptor (fstream)? C++/Linux

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, stream

By accident I found out that I can use read and write on socket descriptors. Can I somehow (ab)use the fstream mechanism to output data into the socket descriptor?

Comment: You can create your own [`streambuf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf) class that can be used by streams. In fact there are some libraries that already does that for you if you search a little.

Comment: Are you looking for [this](http://cboard.cprogramming.com/cplusplus-programming/107187-create-fstream-raw-file-descriptor.html#post788461)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The standard file stream doesn't support use of a file descriptor. However, the I/O stream classes make it reasonably easy to create your own abstraction which allows creating your own sources of or destination for characters. The magic class is `std::streambuf` whose responsibility is to buffer characters and read or write characters at appropriate times. Nicolai Josuttis's ["The C++ Standard Library"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321623215) has a detailed description of how to do so (the basis of which I contributed to Nico many years ago). A simple implementation of a stream buffer using a socket for reading and writing would look something like this:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <streambuf>
#include <cstddef>
#include <unistd.h>

class fdbuf
    : public std::streambuf
{
private:
    enum { bufsize = 1024 };
    char outbuf_[bufsize];
    char inbuf_[bufsize + 16 - sizeof(int)];
    int  fd_;
public:
    typedef std::streambuf::traits_type traits_type;

    fdbuf(int fd);
    ~fdbuf();
    void open(int fd);
    void close();

protected:
    int overflow(int c);
    int underflow();
    int sync();
};

fdbuf::fdbuf(int fd)
  : fd_(-1) {
    this->open(fd);
}

fdbuf::~fdbuf() {
    this->close();
}

void fdbuf::open(int fd) {
    this->close();
    this->fd_ = fd;
    this->setg(this->inbuf_, this->inbuf_, this->inbuf_);
    this->setp(this->outbuf_, this->outbuf_ + bufsize - 1);
}

void fdbuf::close() {
    if (!(this->fd_ < 0)) {
        this->sync();
        ::close(this->fd_);
    }
}

int fdbuf::overflow(int c) {
    if (!traits_type::eq_int_type(c, traits_type::eof())) {
        *this->pptr() = traits_type::to_char_type(c);
        this->pbump(1);
    }
    return this->sync() == -1
        ? traits_type::eof()
        : traits_type::not_eof(c);
}

int fdbuf::sync() {
    if (this->pbase() != this->pptr()) {
        std::streamsize size(this->pptr() - this->pbase());
        std::streamsize done(::write(this->fd_, this->outbuf_, size));
        // The code below assumes that it is success if the stream made
        // some progress. Depending on the needs it may be more
        // reasonable to consider it a success only if it managed to
        // write the entire buffer and, e.g., loop a couple of times
        // to try achieving this success.
        if (0 < done) {
            std::copy(this->pbase() + done, this->pptr(), this->pbase());
            this->setp(this->pbase(), this->epptr());
            this->pbump(size - done);
        }
    }
    return this->pptr() != this->epptr()? 0: -1;
}

int fdbuf::underflow()
{
    if (this->gptr() == this->egptr()) {
        std::streamsize pback(std::min(this->gptr() - this->eback(),
                                       std::ptrdiff_t(16 - sizeof(int))));
        std::copy(this->egptr() - pback, this->egptr(), this->eback());
        int done(::read(this->fd_, this->eback() + pback, bufsize));
        this->setg(this->eback(),
                   this->eback() + pback,
                   this->eback() + pback + std::max(0, done));
    }
    return this->gptr() == this->egptr()
        ? traits_type::eof()
        : traits_type::to_int_type(*this->gptr());
}

int main()
{
    fdbuf        inbuf(0);
    std::istream in(&inbuf);
    fdbuf        outbuf(1);
    std::ostream out(&outbuf);

    std::copy(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(in),
              std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(),
              std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>(out));
}
```

Comment: Correction:  there are two bugs in this snippet (that cancel each other out).  When `overflow()` is called, `*pptr` should not be written to.  You must first `sync()` to make room to write again.  However, this is OK because of the second issue, which is that `setp` takes a pointer to one-past-the-end instead of a pointer to the last element (so the -1 should be removed once the overflow bug is fixed).

Comment: @BenDarnell: actually, both of these actions are done quite deliberately! The buffer reported to `setp()` is one character smaller than it actually is *because* this location will be used in `overflow()` to hold the extra character (if any). That is, I don't see a good reason why the overflowing character should be store in a then empty buffer rather than being sent with the batch of buffered characters. I'm quite sure that there is no mandate that the stream buffer setting up the buffer can't add characters to it (assuming it arranged for the necessary space).

Comment: The call to pbump(1) puts pptr outside the range from pbase to epptr, which is an error (resulting in undefined behavior) according to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/streambuf/streambuf/pbump/.  It doesn't look like this is enforced (at least in the version of libc++ that I'm using), but an STL implementation that stuck to the letter of the spec could still consider this an error.

Comment: @BenDarnell: It certainly isn't enforced and the standard actually doesn't mandate any specific constraints on how `overflow()` is being implemented! There is one [minor] questionable aspect and that is calling `sync()` without fully qualifying the stream buffer type: in theory, a further derived stream buffer could have overwritten `sync()` in which case there could be a problem. The constraints on the setting of the pointer apply while control is passed to the IOStreams library but while implementing a specific stream buffer it is perfectly fine to adjust violate the constraints.

Comment: @BenDarnell: Looking at 27.6.3.3.3 [streambuf.put.area] paragraph 4 doesn't make any precondition on the argument of `pbump()`. It literally state "void pbump(int n); Effects: Adds n to the next pointer for the output sequence." There are some constraints on how the pointers are set but while controlling what's going on these clearly don't apply. Also, since you mention `libc++`: it does exactly the same trick in `std::basic_filebuf`'s `overflow()`!