# Streaming binary files in C++

Tags: c++, iostream

Coming from C, I'm experimenting with C++ a bit and have stumbled on something as simple as reading binary data from a file into a buffer using an `ifstream`. It seems to me that I have three options to read data from the file:

- `get()`, which gets a single character which seems weird and inefficient for reading a greater bulk of data into a memory buffer;
- `read()`, which doesn't return how many characters it actually read; and
- `readsome()`, which, if I understand it correctly, only returns previously buffered data but doesn't read anything new from the actual file.

What strikes me as particularly weird is the `read()` function, which seems to me to be completely unusable seeing as how it doesn't tell how many bytes it actually put into the supplied buffer. Yet all the sample code I see that use it seems to verify that to be the case, and commonly seek to the end of the file to fetch the size of the file and allocate the buffer thereafter. Clearly, this doesn't work for streaming data, however.

So how is one actually supposed to stream a file/pipe/socket with non-text data in C++? Is there some better facility than `ifstream`, perhaps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What strikes me as particularly weird is the read() function, which seems to me to be completely unusable seeing as how it doesn't tell how many bytes it actually put into the supplied buffer.

`read()` does not exit until either 1) the requested number of characters have been read, 2) EOF is reached, or 3) an error occurs.

After `read()` exits, if the read was successful, you can call `gcount()` to find out how many characters were read into the buffer.  If EOF was reached during the read, the stream's `eofbit` state will be set to true, and `gcount()` will return fewer characters than you requested.

If the read fails, the stream's `failbit` and/or `badbit` state is set to true.

```
std::ifstream ifs(...);
if (is) {
    // stream opened...
    //...
    ifs.read(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    if (ifs) {
        // read succeeded, EOF may have been reached...
        std::streamsize numInBuf = ifs.gcount();
        //...
    } else {
        // read failed...
    }
    //...
} else {
    // stream not opened...
}
```

If you use the stream's `exceptions()` method to enable error reporting via exceptions, an `std::ios_base::failure` exception may be thrown if the failure matches the error bits you have enabled exceptions for.

```
std::ifstream ifs;
ifs.exceptions(std::ifstream::badbit | std::ifstream::failbit);
try {
    ifs.open(...);
    // stream opened...
    //...
    ifs.read(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    // read succeeded, EOF may have been reached...
    std::streamsize numInBuf = ifs.gcount();
    //...
} catch (const std::ios_base::failure &e) {
    // stream failure...
}
```

> So how is one actually supposed to stream a file/pipe/socket with non-text data in C++? Is there some better facility than ifstream, perhaps?

`std::ifstream` is designed for file-based streams.  In the case of pipes, if your platform can access pipes via standard file APIs, `std::ifstream` should work.  For sockets though, you need to use a more appropriate `std::basic_istream` derived class, or at least use a standard `std::istream` with a custom `std::streambuf` derived class attached to it ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13542806/65863)).

Comment: Ah, `gcount()` seems to be what I was missing, indeed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> *"What strikes me as particularly weird is the `read()` function, which seems to me to be completely unusable seeing as how it doesn't tell how many bytes it actually put into the supplied buffer."*

Well, you specify how many bytes may be read as a maximum in one go, and may check if the stream is already exhausted afterwards using `std::ifstream::eof()` to check the state.

If you want to know how many bytes are already available from the file, and allocate your read buffer accordingly you may check the whole file size beforehand as mentioned with slight modifications of that sample code from [the reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read):

```
// read entire file into string
std::ifstream is("test.txt", std::ifstream::binary);
if (is) {
    // get length of file:
    is.seekg(0, is.end);
    int length = is.tellg();
    is.seekg(0, is.beg);

    std::string str;
    str.resize(length, ' '); // ******* reserve space ********
    char* begin = &*str.begin();

    is.read(begin, length);
    is.close();

    std::cout << str << "\n";
} else {
    std::cout << "Could not open test.txt\n";
}
```

Note that the crucial point for your question is, if you are able to allocate `length` completely in one go, or if you have to split up reading smaller chunks and parsing those serially when you're not able to provide a buffer that's being able to hold the complete file size.

> *"Clearly, this doesn't work for **streaming data**, however."*

That's just a question of decoupling received chunks of data from an asynchronous task to a higher level thread consuming the data in a *streaming* manner as ever you wish.

Comment: `is.seekg(0, is.end);` -- That won't work on eg. pipes or sockets, though.

Comment: @Dolda2000 Well, you should clarify that concern in your question. I'd prefer just using [`read()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read) and a [`poll()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/poll) loop to read from any input streams though.

Comment: Well, that's why I spoke about "streaming". I was assuming that would be clear enough. Especially since I specifically objected precisely against this particular case in the question. :)